# get sub string in shell script

Tags: string, shell

if I have a string like `some/unknown/amount/of/sub/folder/file.txt` how can I get only the the `file.txt` sub string, remove the front part, while the **length is unknown**.

thank you

EDIT: file name could be any length, and sub folders could be any levels.

Comment: uh...I'm not sure, GNU bash?? is that what you are asking? o.O!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `basename` command:

```
orig_path="some/unknown/amount/of/sub/folder/file.txt"
last_comp=$(basename $orig_path)
echo $last_comp
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$ basename "some/unknown/amount/of/sub/folder/file.txt"
file.txt
```

To generically extract a substring, you can use this syntax

```
$ hello="abcdef"
$ echo ${hello:1:3}
bcd
```

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that the correct answer is to invoke basename, in bash you can also use ## to delete the longest occurrence of a string from the start of a variable.

```
bash-3.2$ t=/this/is/a/path
bash-3.2$ echo ${t##*/}
path
```

Answer (score 4):

basename some/unknown/amount/of/sub/folder/file.txt